# read_enrolment() function not adding names from second text file to tuples list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to define a function named `read_enrolment(a_dict, filename, course_code)`. The function reads this enrolment data and adds the data into the parameter dictionary.

The "key" of `a_dict` is `course_code` and the "value" is a list of UNIQUE students enrolled in the course.

The function should obtain a list of name tuples by calling the `create_name_list(filename)`. It adds a dictionary item into the parameter dictionary if the course code does not exist in the dictionary. If the course code already exists in the dictionary, the function should add the new names to the existing list in the dictionary item.
For example:

```
data = {}
read_enrolment(data, "100.txt", "100")
print(data)
read_enrolment(data, 'extra_100.txt', "100")
print(data)
```

produces

```
{'100': [('Paul', 'Kim'), ('Michael', 'Hill'), ('Alan', 'Wong')]}
{'100': [('Paul', 'Kim'), ('Michael', 'Hill'), ('Alan', 'Wong'), ('Joseph', 'Davis'),('Henry', 'Anderson'), ('Anna', 'Wilson')] }
```

The "100.txt" file contains the following names:

```
Paul Kim
Michael Hill
Alan Wong
```

And the "extra_100.txt" file contains the following names:

```
Joseph Davis
Michael Hill
Anna Wilson
```

Therefore, the final names list is

```
{'100': [('Paul', 'Kim'), ('Michael', 'Hill'), ('Alan', 'Wong'), ('Joseph', 'Davis'), ('Anna', 'Wilson')] }
There are only five tuples in the dictionary item as "Michael Hill" is repeated.
```

I have defined the `create_name_list` reads the contents of the file specified in the parameter.

```
def create_name_list(filename):
    nl = []
    try:
        input_file = open(filename, 'r')
        contents = input_file.read().split("\n")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        if filename == "":
            print ("ERROR: Invalid filename!")
        else:
            print ("ERROR: The file '{}' does not exist.".format(filename))
    else:
        for item in contents:
            name_idx = item.find(" ")
            name = item[:name_idx]
            surname = item[name_idx + 1:]
            nl.append((name, surname))
        return nl
        input_file.close()
```

For eg:

```
>>>filename = "100.txt"
print(create_name_list(filename))

[('Paul', 'Kim'), ('Michael', 'Hill'), ('Alan', 'Wong')] #output
```

These are the contents of the file:

```
Paul Kim
Michael Hill
Alan Wong
```

Below is my `read_enrolment()` function but that is not giving me the output expected:

```
def read_enrolment(a_dict,filename,course_code):
    name_list = create_tuples_list(filename)
    if course_code not in a_dict:
        a_dict[course_code] = name_list
    else:
        for tup in name_list:
            if tup not in a_dict[course_code]:
                a_dict[course_code].append(tup)
```

TEST:

```
a_dict = {}
read_enrolment(a_dict, '100.txt', "100")
read_enrolment(a_dict, 'input_error.txt', "100")
print(a_dict)
```

EXPECTED:

```
ERROR: The file 'input_error.txt' does not exist.
{'100': [('Paul', 'Kim'), ('Michael', 'Hill'), ('Alan', 'Wong')]}
```

GOT:

```
ERROR: The file 'input_error.txt' does not exist.

***Error***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__tester__.python3", line 64, in <module>
    read_enrolment(a_dict, 'input_error.txt', "100")
  File "__tester__.python3", line 13, in read_enrolment
    for tup in name_list:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Where in your function you think you handle the case when key already exists? There is room for a lot of improvements in your code, but answering this will help solve the problem.

Comment: I modified my function but now it shows up another problem for a new case

Comment: if you can please explain why that error cropped up I think I can do it

Comment: Note that there is message `ERROR: The file 'input_error.txt' does not exist.`, so it executed the except block, then just end the function and returns implicit `None`. It fails on creating the `name_list`, not on the if/else part

Comment: ok I'm still not sure I understand. So the error is in the except block?

Comment: No, it just cannot find the file. That leads to executing the `except` block. Then it just exit the function, without executing the `else` block. There is no explicit return in this case, so it just returns `None`. Walk trough your code when it cannot find the file, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: So how can i make my function execute the `else` block? Do I add a `return` statement somewhere?

Comment: If it cannot find the file what it would do in the else block??? You can return empty list in the except block if you want. How can we tell what to do - it's up to you how you want to proceed.

Comment: But the problem is I cannot modify the `create_tuples_list()` function. That is pre-defined.

Comment: Then pass path to existing file or check that return value is not None or empty list. e.g. `if name_list:` then process it...

Comment: So what if I say something like `if name_list != None:` That should work right?

Comment: just `if name_list:` - this will be True in case of non-empty list. `None` is also evaluated as False. Check [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). If you want to check for just being not None - `if name_list is not None:`.

Comment: By the way, the function `create_name_list` has its issues, so if it is pre-defined by tutor, it doubtful how good they are. Apart from the problem with returning None on exception, it will never execute `input_file.close()` line.